# Error "error Couldn't find package "XXX" when building project on CI pipeline and when trying to add packages via Yarn

Tags: reactjs, frontend, yarnpkg

After returning to our project after the weekend my team was met with the error "*error Couldn't find package "3d-view@^2.0.0" required by "gl-plot3d@^2.4.2" on the "npm" registry.*" on our CI pipeline during the install phase. Additionally, this error occurred when trying to add packages with yarn, terminating the process.

This error is happening on the front-end side of our project and doesn't show up upon starting it normally via yarn start. On the last push before the weekend everything went normal without any errors.

Log of our CI job starting at the install command:

```
$ yarn install
 yarn install v1.17.3
 info No lockfile found.
 [1/4] Resolving packages...
 warning @material-ui/core > popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
 warning moments > myconf > babel > babel-core > minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
 warning moments > myconf > babel > babel-core > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
 warning plotly.js > regl-splom > left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
 warning plotly.js > ndarray-fill > cwise > static-module > through2 > xtend > object-keys@0.4.0: 
 warning plotly.js > point-cluster > bubleify > buble > os-homedir@2.0.0: This is not needed anymore. Use `require('os').homedir()` instead.
 error Couldn't find package "3d-view@^2.0.0" required by "gl-plot3d@^2.4.2" on the "npm" registry.
 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Our .gitlab-ci.yml code:

```
stages:
  - build
#  - test
#  - deploy

before_script:
#  - echo `pwd` # debug
#  - echo "$CI_BUILD_NAME, $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME $CI_BUILD_STAGE" # debug
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
  - unset CI

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches

build backend:
  image: gradle:6.1-jdk8
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd backend
    - gradle war

    
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - backend/build/libs/*.jar
    expire_in: 1 week
    
build frontend:
  image: node:10.16.3
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd frontend
    - yarn install
    - export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
    - yarn build
```

Dependencies in package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "moments": "^0.0.2",
    "plotly.js": "^1.52.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-plotly.js": "^2.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0"
  }
```

We are clueless of how this could happen, as nobody pushed anything to the branch in the meantime and was noticed when a team member was pushing a cleaned up version of our code and another was trying to install a new package via Yarn.

Comment: Got the same problem. Looks like `yarn` is failing to resolve "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/3d-view/2.0.0" for whatever reason. Will update when we get it solved on our side if no one beats me to it.

Comment: facing same issue. Any workaround?

Comment: Seems that the issue is with the `yarn` cloudflare servers resolved by the CNAME's. Managed to workaround the issue by using the `yarn.npmjs.org` registry directly i.e.: `yarn add 3d-view@2.0.0 --registry https://yarn.npmjs.org`

Comment: For us it is installed with plotly.js so I am not sure if your solution can help with that? Do you know a way around that? Or is it smarter to just install it separately?

Comment: @FelixBloch e.g. not familiar with `gitlab-ci` but looks like if you amend the `.gitlab-ci.yml`'s `build_frontend.script` > `yarn install` command and set a different registry (i.e. https://yarn.npmjs.org) then should probably work all right.

Comment: @masseyb Yes that fixed the issue. Thanks a lot! Apparently this issue does not exist for users with Yarn 2, my teammate just noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue has been addressed and fixed already but here are some viable solutions found to other answers and our own research in case this happens again:

1) Add 3d-view to yarn.lock before installing it and adding Plotly.js or any other packages:

```
    "3d-view@^2.0.0":
  version "2.0.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/3d-view/-/3d-view-2.0.0.tgz#831ae942d7508c50801e3e06fafe1e8c574e17be"
  integrity sha1-gxrpQtdQjFCAHj4G+v4ejFdOF74=
  dependencies:
    matrix-camera-controller "^2.1.1"
    orbit-camera-controller "^4.0.0"
    turntable-camera-controller "^3.0.0"
```

2) Manually install the package with a registry added:

```
yarn add 3d-view@2.0.0 --registry https://yarn.npmjs.org
```

*Thanks to the user **masseyb***

```
npm i git://github.com/mikolalysenko/3d-view
```

*Thanks to the user **Diogo Falcão***

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix installing the missing package manually:

```
sudo npm i git://github.com/mikolalysenko/3d-view
sudo npm install
```

Comment: This is a great solution for most projects. If you use yarn you just have to adapt the command.