# Express js npm install fails reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, bcrypt

I have a Node.JS / Express.JS server-side program, which I run inside a Node.JS docker container. It was working for the last ~2 years, now it produces a strange error upon installing.
I use docker-compose to install / run the program.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10
ARG PORT
ENV PORT ${PORT}

# Create app directory
ADD backend /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm ci --only=production

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD ["npm", "run", "start-prod"]
```

When I try to install it (with `docker-compose`, it fails every time, with this message:

```
Building backend
Step 1/10 : FROM node:10
 ---> a8441ebf4e4d
Step 2/10 : ARG PORT
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d985b4141806
Step 3/10 : ENV PORT ${PORT}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e053f5bb49fa
Step 4/10 : ADD backend /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 409d0ab160ea
Step 5/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b7aad109486b
Step 6/10 : RUN cp environment-prod-docker.js environment.js
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 218df5ff1cff
Step 7/10 : RUN cat environment.js
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87965e20e57e
Step 8/10 : RUN npm ci --only=production
 ---> Running in 9352da8c367e
npm WARN prepare removing existing node_modules/ before installation
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/bcryptjs/-/bcryptjs-2.4.3.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
```

I have read that it might be possible that this is a proxy error. I have tried to change to my home wifi, my home cable, and mobile data: still produced the same error. If I copy the link, I can download the said .tgz file from the browser.

Comment: `EAI_AGAIN` means DNS is unable to resolve the host

Comment: You can [try setting a different registry to install the packages from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60221742/1423507) if it's an issue with their servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem disappeared after two days (same network, same computer etc.)

It is probably related to what the comments indicated.

Comment: Yeah I got this error when trying to run my server through docker-compose, but a computer restart worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple DNS issue, check `/etc/resolv.conf` and add this:

```
"nameserver 8.8.8.8"
```